# How to limit user access to React Components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Scenario is: I want to hide few React Components for users with Trial Expired. They should be able to login the APP but not view the Components.

Currently, I am using approach which I realized is very bad. I am storing user Trial information in a Redux State

```
USER_TRIAL_EXPIRE = true
```

This can easily be manipulated and any user can access the components with their trial expired.

What should be the approach?

Comment: aren't you storing `expire` stuff in database ??